# ordering 4 events per year into absolute numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, time, formatting

I have a quite simple problem, but for some reason I just can't wrap my head around the solution. I'm trying to do this in R, but really, this is more of a math/mind gymnastics question..

I have data which is organised in this way: - notice the Year 3 event 3 missing

```
 Year    event    
  1        1    
  1        2    
  1        3    
  1        4    
  2        1    
  2        2    
  2        3    
  2        4
  3        1    
  3        2    
  3        4
  3        4
```

And I am trying to obtain a column in which i have a unique number that will go from 1 to 12 (let's call it occasion for every occasion you had since t1 to capture an animal). the result should look like this:

```
 Year    Event       Occasion
  1        1             1
  1        2             2
  1        3             3
  1        4             4
  2        1             5
  2        2             6
  2        3             7
  2        4             8
  3        1             9
  3        2            10
  3        4            12
  3        4            12
```

I also need to do this in a way that if there is a line missing (e.g. no year 3-event 3 in my above example), I will skip the event(absolute values) for this 'occasion' as well and still have 12 as the occasion for event 4 in year 3. I obviously can't simply line them up and count the number of lines since I have multiple lines that will need to be associated to the same occasion (e.g. 2 lines with year3/event4/occasion12)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please first try to solve the problem yourself. If you have a specific question about why your solution (code!) doesn't work as expected, ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a simple formula, as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~event,    
  1,        1,    
  1,        2,    
  1,        3,    
  1,        4,   
  2,        1,   
  2,        2,   
  2,        3,   
  2,        4,
  3,        1,    
  3,        2,    
  3,        4,
  3,        4      
)
df %>%
  mutate(occasion = ((year - 1) * 4) + event)
```

Output:

```
    year event occasion
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1     1        1
2      1     2        2
3      1     3        3
4      1     4        4
5      2     1        5
6      2     2        6
7      2     3        7
8      2     4        8
9      3     1        9
10     3     2       10
11     3     4       12
12     3     4       12
```

Comment: Yes! I think it might just work. I was playing around with the *4, but for some reason didn't manage to get this down! Thanks a lot! I'll let you know how it works